# DataTables loop through the table and delete all rows that contain certain string in certain column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

Been trying to work this out for a while:

In column under index 6 in my DataTable, I have a boolean on Croatian language -> DA for 1 and NE for 0. At one point I want to fire a procedure that will delete all rows that contain "DA" in the column under index 6, however, after the following procedure:

```
function deleteSelectedDiscountedProducts() {
    tableSelectedProducts.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
        var currentData = this.data();
        if (currentData[6].indexOf("DA") >= 0) {
            tableSelectedProducts.row(rowIdx).remove().draw(false);
        } else {

        }
    } );
}
```

I get only one row deleted (probably the first one detected) and the following in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '6' of undefined
```

Also, I tried switching tableSelectedProducts.row(rowIdx).remove().draw(false); with this.remove().draw(false); and it does absolutely the same error deleting only the first row it detects.

What is happening in the background and how to solve this? It seems to me that after deleting one row all the data from the datatable doesn't exist anymore (column under index 6 is undefined) and when I tried to console.log(this) for each of the rows detected, I don't get any output after the first detected row is deleted, but an error above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is bad practice to delete array items by their indexes in a loop. Once you have deleted one item all indexes may have been changed. It is better to pick up a list of the row dom `nodes` you want to delete, and then delete them. Here is an  example :

```
$('#delete').on('click', function() {
  var nodes = [];
  table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    if (this.data()[3] == 'Edinburgh') nodes.push(this.node())
  })
  nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    table.row(node).remove().draw()
  })
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/LqzLzxon/**

Comment: Simple yet splendid! I never thought that once one row is removed indexes are changed. Thank you Sir, you are a genius.

Comment: How come when I try to implement this method, rowIdx, tableLoop, and rowLoop are all UNDEFINED?

Comment: @paparush, Cant tell without the code. But be aware that `every` was first introduced in 1.10.6 and has evolved since. You are perhaps using an older version.